# Which is correct, the late 80s or late 80s without the?

Tags: articles

I was listening to the best 80s music CDs and it made me feel like moving to the US. In my diary, I have written this sentence, but I am not sure whether I should omit the article "the" before "late 80s":

> Some of my best friends moved to the US in the late 80s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20the%20late%20%2780s%2Cin%20late%20%2780s&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20late%20%2780s%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20late%20%2780s%3B%2Cc0)"***in the late '80s***" is the common expression. The use of the definite  article is correct because you are referring to a specific period of time.

Answer (score 2):

Articles are not used before nouns if the noun is being used in a general or abstract sense, or being used to talk about the type of something instead of actual things.

> Some of my best friends moved to the US in the late 80s.

You are not using "late 80's" abstractly, in a general sense, or as a type here.  So, you use the article.